# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a\sin^2x+b \log\cos x}{x^4}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: limits

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a\sin^2x+b \log\cos x}{x^4}=\frac{1}{2}$

My work:

Since the LHS is in indeterminate form, I applied L'Hospital's rule successively and got this equation : $4a+b=-6$.

How can I get another relation between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Why do you think you need another relation on $a$ and $b$? It is not inconceivable that the answer is in fact $\{a,b\in \mathbf{R}: 4a+b=-6\}$.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis: I don't understand what you are saying. The question asks for **values** of $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also we need $2a-b=0$.

Indeed, $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a\sin^2x+b \log\cos x}{x^4}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2a\sin x\cos{x}-b \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}}{4x^3}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2a\cos{x}-b\cdot \frac{1}{\cos{x}}}{4x^2},$$
which gives $2a-b=0$.

Now, $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2a\cos{x}-b\cdot \frac{1}{\cos{x}}}{4x^2}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{2a\cos^2{x}-b}{4x^2}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{-4a\cos{x}\sin{x}}{8x}=-\frac{a}{2},$$
which gives $a=-1$ and $b=-2$.

Comment: The conclusion $2a-b=0$ should be reached by examining the case $2a-b\neq 0$ as explained in comments to another answer here.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a\sin^2x+b \log\cos x}{x^4}=\\
\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a2\sin x\cos x+b \frac{-\sin x}{\cos x}}{4x^3}=\\
\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a\sin 2x-b \tan x}{4x^3}=\\$$
w.r.t $\space  \bf{\sin x \sim x- \frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^5)\space ,\space\space\tan x\sim x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^5)}$
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a(2x- \frac{8x^3}{6})-b (x+ \frac{x^3}{3})}{4x^3}=\\
\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x(2a-b)+\frac{x^3}{3}(-4a-b)}{4x^3}=\frac{1}{2}\\so \\\text{2a-b  must be zero}
 \\
\begin{cases}2a-b=0\\\dfrac{-4a-b}{12}=\frac12\end{cases}\\2a=b\\a=-1,b=-2$$

Comment: @farruhota:thank you for notice

Comment: @Khosrotash: Thank you so much for this solution!

Comment: You should write $\sin x=x-(x^{3}/6)+o(x^{3}),\tan x=x+(x^{3}/3)+o(x^{3})$ rather than use the symbol $\sim$. Further the more subtle issue is in reaching the conclusion $(2a-b)=0$.If $(2a-b)\neq 0$ then $(a\sin 2x-b\tan x) /4x^{3}$ diverges and hence by L'Hospital's Rule the original limit diverges. Thus $(2a - b) =0$ and then the expression tends to $- (4a+b)/12$ and by L'Hospital's Rule this must be equal to original limit $1/2$. Remember that L'Hospital's Rule works like $f'/g'\to L\Rightarrow f/g\to L$ and $\textbf{not like} f/g\to L\Rightarrow f'/g'\to L$.